# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "ponerse las botas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, modismos, expresiones, españa

El DRAE define [**bota (2)**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5xtSA0h%7C5xuY3CS) como:

> 1. f. Calzado, generalmente de cuero, que resguarda el pie, el tobillo y, a veces, una parte de la pierna. Bota de montar, de montaña, de esquí.
> 2. f. Especie de borceguí de piel o tela que usaban las mujeres.
> 3. f. Esp. Calzado de material resistente que, por lo general, no cubre el tobillo y se usa para la práctica de ciertos deportes. Bota de fútbol.

y a continuación define ***ponerse las botas*** como:

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Enriquecerse o lograr un provecho extraordinario.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Aprovecharse extremadamente, y muchas veces desconsideradamente, de algo.
> 3. loc. verb. coloq. Hartarse de algo placentero. Nos pusimos las botas en el restaurante.
> 4. loc. verb. coloq. Col., Méx. y Perú. Entrar en acción, actuar.
> 5. loc. verb. El Salv. y Méx. Mostrar firmeza de carácter o autoridad.
> 6. loc. verb. Méx. Imponer su voluntad.

Las acepciones (4), (5) y (6) podrían  derivar de la acción *ponerse las botas* tomada en sentido literal (para entrar en acción) o figurado (como símbolo de mando y autoridad).

Sin embargo, no veo una relación, ni siquiera remota, con las acepciones (1), (2) y (3), usadas en España.

---

Salvo error por mi parte, el DRAE no recoge la expresión hasta la edición de 1884, y únicamente con el significado de "Enriquecerse o lograr extraordinaria conveniencia"; en 1983 añade "Aprovecharse extremadamente, y muchas veces desconsideradamente, de algo" y solo en 2001 añade "Hartarse de algo placentero".

Comment: Si la respuesta de @fedorqui es la que estabas buscando, debemos colocarle a la pregunta una etiqueta de región ya que en la mayoría de latinoamérica el significado de **"alistarse para la acción"** o de **"actuar de forma decidida"** no tiene nada que ver con el significado de España de _enriquecerse o hartarse_

Comment: En wordreference encontré que en Chile y Argentina (los que faltaban) se usa igual que en Colombia, México, Perú y Salvador. Con esto se puede ya casi asegurar que toda latinoamérica usa la expresión de manera completamente diferente al uso en España

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por dar una respuesta diferente, aunque no disponga de ninguna referencia: es cierto que la expresión ponerse las botas aparece por primera vez en el diccionario de la academia de 1884. Sin embargo, ya en el diccionario de autoridades (tomo I, 1726) se puede leer:

> **Estar con las botas calzadas**. Vale lo mismo que estar pronto à hacer viage, y prevenido de todo lo necessário para él.

Esta expresión cambió en la versión de 1770 del diccionario a:

> **Estár con las botas puestas**. Fras. que vale estár para hacer viage y metaforicamente estár dispuesto para qualquiera cosa.

Por tanto, no sería descabellado que "ponerse las botas" significara en un principio "prepararse para cualquier cosa", cosa que se podría desprender de ver que alguien estuviera haciendo acopio de bienes (para preparar maletas o lo que fuera). De ahí pasaría la expresión a significar "hacer acopio excesivo" y finalmente a "hartarse de cualquier cosa".

Comment: Tiene sentido. Parte de prepararse para hacer un viaje (sobre todo en 1800)  era comer hasta hartarse porque no se sabía cuando sería la próxima comida. Adicionalmente aquí no solo usamos "ponerse las botas" sino que también usamos **"dormir con las botas puestas"** para referirnos a una situación en la que no vale alistarse sino en la que hay que estar listo en todo momento.

Answer (score 2):

¡Buena pregunta! La tenía en mi lista de "a preguntar" :)

Veo que [Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/) lo contestó hace un tiempo.  Se detalla el significado de las acepciones (1), (2) y (3) de las indicadas en el DRAE, pues este blog está escrito por una persona de España.

De [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión ‘ponerse las botas’?](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-ponerse-las-botas/):

> Hoy en día utilizamos la expresión ‘ponerse las botas’ para indicar
>   que se ha comido mucho y en abundancia o como sinónimo de enriquecerse
>   o aprovecharse de algo, también abundantemente.
>
> El origen de la frase lo encontramos  al unísono con el nacimiento de
>   este tipo de calzado, generalmente de cuero, que en sus inicios era de
>   uso exclusivo de las clases más altas y pudientes.
>
> Los caballeros, que iban provistos de sus botas y sus pies bien
>   resguardados del frio y la suciedad del suelo, eran los que mejor
>   comían y hacían los grandes negocios. Por el contrario, el pueblo
>   llano y sin recursos usaba como calzado las sandalias, alpargatas o
>   sencillos zapatos (en el mejor de los casos).
>
> De ahí que se vinculase el hecho de ponerse (calzarse) las botas con
>   el de tener y/o conseguir algo en abundancia.

Es decir: en su origen, si llevabas botas era porque tenías recursos. Y si tienes recursos, comes bien.

Comment: Oops No tenía ni idea....Esta definición no tiene nada que ver con el uso que le damos en Colombia. En la pregunta está escrito en la definición 4 que por aquí significa "entrar en acción" aunque en realidad la usamos como "**alistarse** para entrar en acción".  En ningún momento la usamos para enriquecerse, aprovecharse o hartarse.

Comment: @DGaleano ah curioso, parece ese un significado más literal. A mí en España solo me consta el significado de las acepciones 1, 2 y 3, que es el que define el blog. He actualizado mi respuesta para hacerlo más claro.

Comment: Podemos solucionarlo con una etiqueta de región "España" en la pregunta y listo :-) Creo que user13560 es de esos lados aunque no hay datos en su perfil

Comment: @DGaleano sí, veo que user13560 añadió tal etiqueta.